# TypeError on Length of a String Characters

Tags: python-3.x

Good evening and thanks in advance for an explanation and resolution from those who reply.

I am coding on Python 3.7, taking a Python Intro summer course.  I am tasked with creating a function requesting 2 user inputs: (1) character key and (2) a string, phrase or sentence between 4 to 500 characters. Both of these function require error handlers.  The first 'character' executed fine. The second 'phrase_sentence' function returned an error stating:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I am following a similar example from our textbook and cannot troubleshoot the error.  I am aware that when it comes to digits (numeric), I have to convert to float or int, but the example and sample code layout the function how I entered it because it is based on length of string characters.  I have also tried enclosing the entire 'if len' statement in parentheses.

```
def main():
    # define keyCharacter function and request user input for a key
    
    character = input('Please enter a single alphabet character (a-z) for a key: ')
    if((character>='a' and character<= 'z') or (character>='A' and character<='Z')):
        print("Your key character is:", character)
    else:
        print("ERROR: Please enter a single alphabet character: ")
        character = (input('Please enter a single alphabet character (a-z) for a key: '))
        
    #theString()    
    phrase_sentence = input('Enter a phrase or sentence, between 4 & 500 characters long: ')
    if len((phrase_sentence) >= 4 and (phrase_sentence) <= 500):
        print("Your phrase or sentence is: ", phrase_sentence)
    else:
        print("ERROR: Sentence or phrase must be between\b 4 & 500 characters, try again!")
        phrase_sentence = input('Enter a phrase or sentence, between 4 & 500 characters long: ')
        
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be in how you called len(). Try this:

```
character = input('Please enter a single alphabet character (a-z) for a key: ')
if((character>='a' and character<= 'z') or (character>='A' and character<='Z')):
    print("Your key character is:", character)
else:
    print("ERROR: Please enter a single alphabet character: ")
    character = (input('Please enter a single alphabet character (a-z) for a key: '))
    
#theString()    
phrase_sentence = input('Enter a phrase or sentence, between 4 & 500 characters long: ')
if len(phrase_sentence) >= 4 and len(phrase_sentence) <= 500:
    print("Your phrase or sentence is: ", phrase_sentence)
else:
    print("ERROR: Sentence or phrase must be between 4 & 500 characters, try again!")
    phrase_sentence = input('Enter a phrase or sentence, between 4 & 500 characters long: ')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's great.  I can't believe how oblivious I was to how obvious the solution was.  Carlos

Comment: No problem, and welcome to SO :). Please mark the question as resolved once it's been solved.